# Getting Firebase error when writing a variable to a path

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm grabbing a URL and parsing it to create a variable called list. I have this variable printing in the console inside and outside of the function. I also have tried grabbing the URL again inside of the function. Firing this function gives me an error of:

> Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.

How can I pass the correct variables to the function so that I can write to Firebase?

The JS is:

```
var getQueryString = function ( field, url ) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i' );
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};

var list = getQueryString('list', window.location.href);
console.log(list);
document.getElementById('list').innerText = list;

function accept(){
  var list = getQueryString('list', window.location.href);
  console.log("accept", "list", list);
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid = user.uid;
  console.log("accept", "uid", uid);
  firebase.database().ref('userprofile/' + uid +  '/list').update(list);
  return firebase.database().ref('userlists/' + list +  '/members/' + uid).update('true');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing now is equivalent to a `set()` operation:

```
return firebase.database().ref('userlists/' + list +  '/members/' + uid).set('true');
```

Alternatively you can perform the update one level higher:

```
var updates = {};
updates[uid] = 'true';
return firebase.database().ref('userlists/' + list +  '/members/' + ).update(updates);
```

Comment: Making this change still results in an error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo in the definition of `updates`. I fixed it in the answer.